# Can not click button when a method running

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

```
   private void AddMyScrollEventHandlers()
   {
       VScrollBar vScrollBar1 = new VScrollBar();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       while (true)
       {
           if (vScrollBar1.Value + 1 < vScrollBar1.Maximum)
           {
               vScrollBar1.Value = vScrollBar1.Value + 1;    
               label1.Text = vScrollBar1.Value.ToString();                       
           }       
           else 
           {         
               break;      
           }

           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
       }
   }

   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // vScrollBar1.Scroll
   }
```

I am new in C#. I was working on scroll. What I wanted here is, if anyone click button1 then scroll automatically move to the end and I wanted to show gradual value in label1. Also when someone click button2 scrolling stop.

Now the problem is label1 do not show gradual change in value. It shows value once when the scrolling stop.

Also when scrolling continue i,e when while loop is working I can not click on button2. Actually I can not click on the form even.

Someone please give me some idea how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

This happens because the thread that is performing the task is busy, and it's the same thread that updates the UI. You can use a multithreading solution. Take a look at 
[`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: BackgroundWorker is not suited for this scenario. All the process is UI-related. He could easily use a windows forms timer.

Comment: You are right, but I suppose that `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);` represents the task that will be performing in the `DoWork`. Otherwise, the code doesn't has many sense

Comment: Well, this is what exactly the [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) is designed for.

Answer (score 1):

All the UI events run in the main thread of the application, so the application can only process one event at a time. When the application is processing an event, no other event will be processed.

Since you are doing a UI related work periodically, the best option is to use the [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) class:

1. Drop `Timer` from the toolbox into the form.
2. In the properties window, set the interval to 200.
3. Double click the timer object to create the `Tick` event handler.
4. Put this code in the newly created `timer1_Tick` method:

   ```
    if (vScrollBar1.Value + 1 < vScrollBar1.Maximum)
    {
        vScrollBar1.Value = vScrollBar1.Value + 1;    
        label1.Text = vScrollBar1.Value.ToString();                       
    }       
    else 
    {         
        timer1.Stop();
    }
   ```
5. Change your methods as below:

   ```
   private void AddMyScrollEventHandlers()
   {
       timer1.Start();
   }

   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       timer1.Stop();
   }
   ```

Now you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `BackgroundWorker` control, as suggested by *Agustin Meriles*. However, one more important thing to note is that You should use `Control.Invoke(...)` method to update controls from another thread.

I've modified Your code, tested it in a sample application and it seems to work correctly.

First, add a new `BackgroundWorker` control to Your form and assign `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` to its `DoWork` event.

Then, You can use the code below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code from here is moved to BackgroundWorker control
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //while (true)
    //the condition directly in the while looks more clear to me
    while (vScrollBar1.Value + 1 < vScrollBar1.Maximum)
    {
        //update controls using Invoke method and anonymous functions
        vScrollBar1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { vScrollBar1.Value += 1; });

        label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { label1.Text = vScrollBar1.Value.ToString(); });

        //when called inside BackgroundWorker, this sleeps the background thread, 
        //so UI should be responsive now
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

If You have any problems when using this code, please let me know.

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments, You could also use `ProgressChanged` event of the `BackgroundWorker`. It requires some more changes in the code, but is more suitable in this case. You can find some information about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx.

If You are not going to add any other code with more processing in the `while` loop, You can also use `Timer` control, as suggested by *MD.Unicorn* in his answer.

Comment: `ProgressChagned` event and `ReportProgress` method of the `BackgroundWorker` class are designed to eliminate this. There is no need to use `Invoke` by using them. Actually, using a `Timer` solves all this more easily.

Comment: Yes, you could use `ReportProgress` as well. `Timer` is more suitable in this particular case, if no additional processing is added in the `while` loop, but if person asking the question would like to improve the code and add some other calculations etc., `BackgroundWorker` may be better.